# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - Implementing Leaderboard

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add a leaderboard in a game using Google Play Game Services.

Classes in which I display leaderboard and submit score extend Screen from Framework, so I created that Screen extends BaseGameActivity, which is required to use Google Play Game Services.

I get this error when I start app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
            at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:784)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:76)
            at com.x.x.BaseGameActivity.<init>(BaseGameActivity.java:65)
            at com.x.framework.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:8)
            at com.x.x.LoadingScreen.<init>(LoadingScreen.java:11)
            at com.x.x.SplashLoadingScreen.update(SplashLoadingScreen.java:19)
            at com.x.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:47)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Part of code where error is pointing:

BaseGameActivity.java

```
...protected BaseGameActivity() {
    super();
}...
```

Screen.java

```
...public Screen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }...
```

LoadingScreen.java

```
...public LoadingScreen(Game game) {

        super(game);
    }...
```

SplashLoadingScreen.java

```
...game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));...
```

AndroidFastRenderView.java

```
 ...game.getCurrentScreen().update(deltaTime);...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your post, even if it is on hold as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stacktrace, it looks like you are trying to touch views and create Activity in a background thread. You should not. Try to do it on main thread and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't attempt to update user interface from a background thread. Use e.g. `runOnUiThread()` to post a `Runnable` to a handler running on the main UI thread.
2. Don't attempt to instantiate activity classes such as `LoadingScreen` yourself with `new`. Use only `Intent` to indirectly instantiate activities or change your design so that the class you're instantiating is not an `Activity`.